# Limiting value of $\frac{4x^2+2y^2-6xy}{6x^2+√2y-8xy}$ as point $(x,y)$ on curve $x^2+y^2=1$ approaches the position $(\frac1{√2},\frac1{√2})$

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math, coordinate-systems

> The limiting value of expression $\frac{4x^2+2y^2-6xy}{6x^2+√2y-8xy}$ is $A$ as point $(x,y)$ on curve $x^2+y^2=1$ approaches the position $(\frac1{√2},\frac1{√2})$ where $A$ is such that $(5A,0)$ is a point as focus of parabola $S$ having axis parallel to x-axis, vertex at origin. The two common tangents can be drawn to both circle and parabola from an external point; find the coordinates of that point. Also find the locus of midpoints of chords of parabola, which subtend a right angle at vertex of parabola.

**My Attempt:**

At first I thought there is a typo in the denominator and it should be $√2y^2$ but the expression as written is of the form $0/0$, so, then I thought of removing the factors causing $0/0$ form.

Numerator can be factorized as $2(2x-y)(x-y)$. Not able to factorize the denominator.

Then I replaced $x$ by $\cos\theta$ and $y$ by $\sin\theta$, and got

$\frac{(cos\theta-\sin\theta)(3+\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}{3+3\cos2\theta+√2\sin\theta-4\sin2\theta}$,

which is still a $0/0$ form. Don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and subtract $2y^2$ in the denominator

$$6x^2+\sqrt{2}y-8xy+2y^2-2y^2 = 2(3x^2-4xy+y^2)+\sqrt{2}y-2y^2$$

$$ = 2(3x-y)(x-y)+\sqrt{2}y(1-\sqrt{2}y)$$

Combined with the factoring you already recognized, this means we can rewrite your limmand as

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}(2x-y)}{\sqrt{2}(3x-y)+\frac{y(1-\sqrt{2}y)}{(x-y)}} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2+L}\equiv A$$

as we approach $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$. Now $L$ doesn't exist in general as the limit can grow unboundedly along certain paths, for example along $x=y+(1-\sqrt{2}y)^2$.

But we are being told to restrict the calculation of $L$ to one path (along the unit circle), which we will denote $L_{S^1}$. Plug in the path $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$:

$$\require{cancel}L_{S^1} = \lim_{y\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{y(1-\sqrt{2}y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}-y} = \lim_{y\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{y(\sqrt{1-y^2}+y)}{1+\sqrt{2}y}\cdot\frac{\cancel{(1-\sqrt{2}y)}}{\cancel{(1-\sqrt{2}y)}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore your limit is $\boxed{A = \frac{2}{5}}$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\frac{4x^2+2y^2-6xy}{6x^2+y\sqrt{2}-8xy}$

Let $y=kx$

$f(x,kx)=\frac{4x^2+2k^2x^2-6kx^2}{6x^2+kx\sqrt{2}-8kx^2}=\frac{2x(k-1)(k-2)}{(6x+k\sqrt{2}-8kx)}$

$f(\sqrt{2}/2,k\sqrt{2}/2) = \frac{\sqrt{2}(k-1)(k-2)}{3(1-k)\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2-k}{3}$

I think the limit is 1/3.

An alternative

$\frac{(8x-6y)dx+(4y-6x)dy}{(12x-8y)dx+(\sqrt{2}-8x)dy}=\frac{\sqrt{2}dx-\sqrt{2}dy}{2\sqrt{2}dx-3\sqrt{2}dy}=\frac{dx-dy}{2dx-3dy}=\frac{1-dy/dx}{2-3dy/dx}$

$dy/dx$ on the circle at $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ is $-1$. Plugging that in gives you $2/5$.